# In the c# Exception handling is there a way to detect transient errors?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, azure, error-handling

I'm using Azure and I have simple try catch block 
what i'm doing now is when we have any error i'll email the error message now i want to detect transient error and just ignore sending Email for them

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {         
         HandleError(ex);
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
}

protected void HandleError(Exception ex) 
{
      //and here i want to check if the cause of exception is not a transient      error then write a code to email the error details 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: and how do you determine what a transient error is?

Comment: as  written in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx the transient error is: Transient faults are errors that occur because of some temporary condition such as network connectivity issues or service unavailability

Comment: There is no definition of which exceptions are transient. That is determined by the context in which the exception occurs.

Comment: John and how we should determine it by the context can you give me an example?

Comment: I updated my answer to help assist with the point I believe that @JohnSaunders was making in his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link you just posted, and the code sample provided:

```
// Define your retry strategy: retry 3 times, 1 second apart.
var retryStrategy = new FixedInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

// Define your retry policy using the retry strategy and the Azure storage
// transient fault detection strategy.
var retryPolicy = 
  new RetryPolicy<StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

// Do some work that may result in a transient fault.
try
{
  // Call a method that uses Azure storage and which may
  // throw a transient exception.
  retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(
    () =>
    {
        this.queue.CreateIfNotExist();
    });
}
catch (Exception)
{
  // All of the retries failed.
}
```

according to that documentation an exception isn't raised **until** it is no longer a transient error as defined by your retry policy.  In effect - utilizing the transient fault handling application block is already doing what you're asking in your question.  Retries are retried silently (without exception) until a point in time occurs where an exception is raised - when a retry has occurred exceeding your retry policy.

The following should not be taken as "good code", it is merely an example of how the TFHAB ***could*** determine a transient error.

```
private void DoStuff()
{
    try
    {
        this.DoSomethingThatCouldPotentiallyCauseTransientErrors(5);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This would not be caught until the "retries" have occurred.
        this.HandleException(ex);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
}

private void DoSomethingThatCouldPotentiallyCauseTransientErrors(int retryAttemptsBeforeExceptionThrown)
{
    // Note that this will *always throw an exception*, 
    // I'm (attempting to) simply demonstrate my point of how the transient errors could be defined.

    for (int i = 0; i < retryAttemptsBeforeExceptionThrown)
    {
        try    
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            int result = x / y;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (i < retryAttemptsBeforeExceptionThrown-1)
            {
                // Swallow/ignore the exception, and retry
                // Note that anything hitting this block would be considered a "transient error", 
                // as we are not raising an exception
            }
            else
            {
                // Too many failed attempts have occurred, ***now*** we raise an exception to the caller
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void HandleException(Exception ex)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Hopefully that sort of answers your question to John on the context of what makes a "transient error"

Comment: but if i don't want to use and install  the Transient Fault Handling Application Block is there any way to detect and separate transient error from other errors by Exception class? actually I don't want to retry in case of transient error just I want to ignore sending email in that case

Comment: but... transient errors are ***defined*** as per your retry policy.  If you aren't using the `Transient Fault Handling Application Block`, then the errors aren't transient, they're simply exceptions.

Comment: So there is no flag or error number that from them we can detect the cause of exception is a transient error?

Comment: If there were (and I'm not saying there isn't, I do not know the answer) - then it would only be accessible if you were actually using the TFHAB, you've stated you're not, so there's not much you can do.  I'm not really sure at this point what you're hoping to get out of your question.  You haven't clearly defined what a "transient" error is, aside from posting a link to a feature of .net that you have stated you aren't even using, or planning to use.  The TFHAB already disregards transient errors automatically, as was your original quesiton, but you are disregarding it as a useable feature.

Comment: As I stated: Transient faults are errors that occur because of some temporary condition such as network connectivity issues or service unavailability so the feature allow you to retry and other configuration but What I want is to simply to check if the exception is caused by a transient error then ignore sending email

Comment: I'll try again.  "Transient Errors" are defined in HFHAB as per your retry policy.  As you've stated you are not using HFHAB, a "Transient Error" is ***NOT A THING***.  If you are not using the application block, a failure to utilize a resource, is ***simply an exception***.  The HFHAB via the retry policy overrides this default behavior, and states that "retries" are transient errors, exceptions aren't thrown until after the retries fail.  ***If you are not using HFHAB then transient errors do not exist, you have to DEFINE what a transient error is***

Comment: ok Thanks Now I understand , so if we don't retry we can't know that this is transient error or is it for example a null references error?

Comment: correct, your methods that are called via your retry policy are what defines a transient error, no retry policy, no transient errors.

Comment: Kritner thanks for demonstration I think I understood now ;), but let me ask the question in other way how to know the cause of exception was due to server connectivity or service unavailability and not other reasons such as null refrence, I think there should be an easy solution for that

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything like that "easily" as it really depends on your requirements.  You can disregard specific exception types, but you need to define those exceptions to consider "ok".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure Client SDK (a recent version >= v4.3.0.0), the default retry policy is Exponential Retry. That is so even if you do not define any retry policy specifically. The client SDK Exponential retry policy has logic to detect the transient errors based on pretty much the HttpStatusCode returned from the Azure Storage service response. All of these retries will be done transparently to your code, when you make a request to azure storage and if that request fails with an error that the client sdk thinks is transient (pretty much all 5xx Http Status Codes).

if you want to stop the client SDK retries completely and take a full control of this yourself inside your catch block, then you can pass in NoRetry policy as part of your [Table/Blob/Queue]RequestOptions to turn the retries off under the hood which are done by the client SDK.

Then in your catch block, you will need to catch the StorageException s thrown by the client SDK on your failed request, parse the HttpStatusCode embedded in it, make a decision based on that whether the error is transient or not and take corresponding action.

Of course not all exceptions will be StorageException s, you may also get non storage exceptions like null ref etc. you can do the same process for those as well, they will generally be non transient.

If you want to go that route you should know exactly what you are doing, what the actual client SDK is doing in its own transient error detection and retry mechanism and the impact of turning it off completely. I have seen many cases where people fiddle with Azure storage RetryPolicies without fully understanding what it does and end up overloading the service with unnecessary retries which are already retried by the client SDK or causing more latency, lower throughput etc.

Comment: I am currently using the native retry policy provided by the ASB SDK and as you mentioned, it by default uses RetryExponentail retry policy to retry under the hood...what I am interested to know is how can I know the default parameters for the RetryExponential class...also, can you please share any documentation which describes the underlying details...(I have already seen this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-event-hubs-retry-guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Signals from my Apache licensed [Griffin.Framework](http://griffinframework.net)

```
public class YourController
{
    static Signal _errorsignal = Signal.Create("YourController.Error");

    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        try
        {
            //some logic

            //logic succeeded, reset
            _errorSignal.Reset();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            //Raised for the first time, notify
            if (_errorSignal.Raise(ex))
                HandleError(ex); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error"); 
        }

    //[...]
}
```

It keeps track of the state and can also upload state changes (from all signals) to a HTTP server.

Instead of having a HandleError in every controller you can also put the following in your global.asax:

```
//put in the Init method
Signal.SignalRaised += OnGlobalHandling;

public void OnGlobalHandling(object sender, SignalRaisedEventArgs e)
{
    var signal = (Signal)sender;
    //send email
}
```

Comment: In your framework, what is the difference between transient errors and "non-transient" errors?